# Import large volume data in iOS device

Tags: ios, database

1. I have two tables and both have 150000 and 50000 records respectively.
2. The data is coming from web server.
3. Memory and time both are important constraints.

What should I use Core Data or SQLite 3? Please reply urgently.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a request of urgency, especially from a new member is less then polite

Answer (score 1):

SQLite 3 or CoreData are both valid solutions.  Whichever you're most comfortable with, you should use.  I'd suggest CoreData, it will manage some of the memory issues for you. (The next person will suggest SQLite.)

That's a lot of data, and your user will be waiting for a long time.  If the data is not going to change much you should pre-load the app with it.

Comment: Both solutions have their pros and cons. Choose whatever fits best. Maybe this link might be useful: [on switching away from core data](http://inessential.com/2010/02/26/on_switching_away_from_core_data)

Comment: As you suggested I used core data for large data set and at the time of delete operation I observed that memory footprints goes increase and increase. Here I have used [context reset] method as well after saving temporary context in persistence store. So, what should I do for this issue.

Comment: Be more specific about what you are doing and what you are measuring.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data is primarily an object graph. If you don't need its features, choose SQLite. On the other hand, if you can benefit from having a persistent object graph and excellent memory management, Core Data is a good choice.

Comment: But when I used core data with large data set and at the time of delete operation I observed that memory footprints goes increase and increase. Here I have used context reset method as well after saving temporary context in my operation. So, what should I do for this issue.

Comment: Core Data _is not_ a database, even if its persistent store is an SQLite database. It has both advantages and disadvantages of its own. In general, it has a certain overhead anyway, so, even though it's impossible to compare Core Data with SQLite feature-wise, SQLite will almost always win performance-wise when coded properly.